# Sound output approach for Sine waves in C

Tags: audio, c

I am looking for a means to play simple sine waves and other basic math functions in pure C, **not C++/C#**. Are there any libraries or methods to output actively to the sound card? Even more ideally to integrate soundfonts. Is this too cumbersome of an endeavor?

I am a C noob and want to learn more and expand in this area of programming. I have looked all over online and haven't found any clear examples or routes for this. Essentially I plan on making a rudimentary keyboard synth, ie: holding down q plays note A etc.

Any help or redirection would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which kinds of system you're targeting, but most modern Linux desktop distributions have PulseAudio installed as their highest-level audio interface, so you can use its [simple API](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/simple.html) (in particular `pa_simple_write()`) to produce sound.

For soundfonts, I think [FluidSynth's library](https://www.fluidsynth.org/api/index.html) is fairly popular.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! I will read up on those libraries.